# VS2010 Load Tests and Performance Tests included in run all tests

Tags: visual-studio-2010, testing, buildconfiguration

I have a VS2010 solution with different build configurations.  I have been including specific unit test projects in specific build configurations so that when you are working on a specific configuration you only run the associated unit test projects.

This works nicely. (finally)

However, the solution also has a load test project and a performance test project.  Both of these show up in test viewer regardless of build configuration and regardless of the fact that I have done everything in my power to remove them from all but the general debug configuration.

Does anyone know of any way to remove these kinds of projects from the runnable test list for a given build configuration as ... believe it or not ... I do not want my load tests to run every time you select run all tests!

Thanks in advance for any assistance